# What is the conventional way to encrypt double/float data accurately?

Tags: encryption

Basically, i want to encrypt standard ecg data with resolution of 11 bit mostly come from MIT-BIH Arrhythmia Database. The sample point values i saw are decimal like [image].

Suppose that i just want to do simple xor encryption with a set of random generated integer number. How do i accomplish xor of double/float with these integer number?

- I already tried by converting the sample point and the random number into 64 bit binary according to ieee754 standard, but there will be a case of the resulting xor values will be NaN (too big or too smal values with all 1 in exponent part) hence i cant get the float value or plot the encrypted data(because NaN is not a value) to visualize the signal before and after encryption.
- I also already thought of converting the double/float into integers first by multiplying it by 10^N and floor it down but i dont know what is the appropriate N for all ecg data cases because i might have data loss for some sample point cases such as 0.0009823 with N=100 will become 0. I had hunch that to determine the appropriate N depends on the resolution of the ecg data but after reading some related literature i still dont found the answer.

So what i would like to know is what is the best approaches?and what is the most conventional way of encrypting double/float value of ecg data like that?

Comment: What are you trying to visualize after encryption? Encrypted data generally looks random, so there's little value in plotting it

Comment: i would like to visually see how big is the difference between encrypted data and the plaintext data and also i would like to calculate the encrypted data histogram, coefficient correlation, and information entropy

Comment: You've got 64/32-bit (double/float respectively) binary data in. You bitwise XOR that with the random value. You get a random 64/32-bit value out. out, it might not be a valid floating point number (could be ±INF or a NAN). Treat it all as unsigned integers, use that to take the statistics you're interested in.

Comment: Your first approach **is** the best approach. Encrypted data isn't supposed to be able to be graphed. Do you want to weaken the encryption so that you can graph it?

Comment: @SAIPeregrinus why do i have to treat it as unsigned integers?why not as signed integers?is it because signed integers also would have NaN value?also can the statistical test result of the unsigned integers be justified?i mean it was originally a double/float value though the binary form is the same

Comment: @user253751 but how do i evaluate the encryption performance to statistical attack/entropy attack/correlation attack if i cant calculate the histogram,coefficient correlation and information entropy because it contain NaN numbers?

Comment: @MuhammadFauzi encryption encrypts bytes, not floats. Did you consider drawing a histogram of the bytes?

Comment: The encrypted data should be indistinguishable from random values. You could treat it as signed, but it's often easier to treat bytes as unsigned. EG in C several operations on negative signed integers are undefined. It's also easier to read a histogram of values from 0-255 than -127-128.

Comment: thanks a lot guys, i got it now